# Why Kubernetes pods sometimes got CrashLoopBackOff?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vagrant, kubernetes, centos7, rancher

Using Kubernetes cluster: 3 hosts(1 master and 2 nodes).

Kubernetes version: 1.7

Deployed a Rails app to Kubernetes cluster.

Here is the `deployment.yaml` file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: server
  labels:
    app: server
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
  selector:
    app: server
    tier: backend
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: server
  labels:
    app: server
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: server
        tier: backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: 192.168.33.13/myapp/server
        name: server
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
          name: server
        imagePullPolicy: Always
```

Deploy it:

```
$ kubectl create -f deployment.yaml
```

Then check the pods status:

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                                         READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
server-962161505-kw3jf                                       0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   6          9m
server-962161505-lxcfb                                       0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   6          9m
server-962161505-mbnkn                                       0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   6          9m
```

At the beginning, its status got `Completed` but went to `CrashLoopBackOff` soon. Is there anything wrong in the config yaml file?

(By the way, I don't want to run a `entrypoint.sh` script here but used a `job.yaml` file to call k8s `Job` kind to do it.)

## Edit

Result of `kubectl describe pod server-962161505-kw3jf`:

```
Name:           server-962161505-kw3jf
Namespace:      default
Node:           node1/192.168.33.11
Start Time:     Mon, 13 Nov 2017 17:45:47 +0900
Labels:         app=server
                pod-template-hash=962161505
                tier=backend
Annotations:    kubernetes.io/created-by={"kind":"SerializedReference","apiVersion":"v1","reference":{"kind":"ReplicaSet","namespace":"default","name":"server-962161505","uid":"0acadda6-c84f-11e7-84b8-02178ad2db9a","...
Status:         Running
IP:             10.42.254.104
Created By:     ReplicaSet/server-962161505
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/server-962161505
Containers:
  server:
    Container ID:   docker://29eca3d9a20c60c83314101b036d742c5868c3bf25a39f28c5e4208bcdbfcede
    Image:          192.168.33.13/myapp/server
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://192.168.33.13/myapp/server@sha256:0e056e3ff5b1f1084e0946bc4211d33c6f48bc06dba7e07340c1609bbd5513d6
    Port:           3000/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Tue, 14 Nov 2017 10:13:12 +0900
      Finished:     Tue, 14 Nov 2017 10:13:13 +0900
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  26
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-csjqn (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  Initialized    True
  Ready          False
  PodScheduled   True
Volumes:
  default-token-csjqn:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-csjqn
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.alpha.kubernetes.io/notReady:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.alpha.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason                 Age                 From            Message
  ----     ------                 ----                ----            -------
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  22m                 kubelet, node1  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-csjqn"
  Normal   SandboxChanged         22m                 kubelet, node1  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Warning  Failed                 20m (x3 over 21m)   kubelet, node1  Failed to pull image "192.168.33.13/myapp/server": rpc error: code = 2 desc = Error response from daemon: {"message":"Get http://192.168.33.13/v2/: dial tcp 192.168.33.13:80: getsockopt: connection refused"}
  Normal   BackOff                20m (x5 over 21m)   kubelet, node1  Back-off pulling image "192.168.33.13/myapp/server"
  Normal   Pulling                4m (x7 over 21m)    kubelet, node1  pulling image "192.168.33.13/myapp/server"
  Normal   Pulled                 4m (x4 over 20m)    kubelet, node1  Successfully pulled image "192.168.33.13/myapp/server"
  Normal   Created                4m (x4 over 20m)    kubelet, node1  Created container
  Normal   Started                4m (x4 over 20m)    kubelet, node1  Started container
  Warning  FailedSync             10s (x99 over 21m)  kubelet, node1  Error syncing pod
  Warning  BackOff                10s (x91 over 20m)  kubelet, node1  Back-off restarting failed container
```

Comment: Can you add logs of the pod as well ?

Comment: @SureshVishnoi `kubectl logs server-962161505-kw3jf` got message `Switch to inspect mode.` only.

Comment: Send us _describe_ of some pod, ie - `kubectl describe pod server-962161505-kw3jf`. 
Sometimes I have the same error which has many sources. It could be 1) K8s cannot connect to your docker repository, 2) on node is problem with free space on disk, 3) bad set permissions for docker container, ...

Comment: @waldauf I added the result of describe special pod. And your problem list seems very common and useful. I am not sure at my case now. I think the reason is k8s' deployment config yaml file.

Comment: @online It looks as I wrote - problem with docker hub. In _describe_ you see this message: `node1  Failed to pull image "192.168.33.13/myapp/server": rpc error: code = 2 desc = Error response from daemon: {"message":"Get http://192.168.33.13/v2/: dial tcp 192.168.33.13:80: getsockopt: connection refused"}`. Try to connect to node01 and list all images in docker (`docker images`). Can you see there your image? If no try to download it manually (`docker pull <image>`). I think you are missing secrets in deployment. Or you can try to run command `docker login http://192.168.33.13` and pull it.

Comment: @waldauf It can access the docker registry server first time. But it seems went fault from second time. I also checked all the k8s clusters that all of them has `192.168.33.13/myapp/server` image there. I also tried to use docker hub to save the image, and the same result. It's a puzzle.

Comment: @online I'm little bit lost. Did you try `docker pull <image>`? If yes and it failed so try `docker login <docker_hub_server>`. If this doesn't work so there is problem with docker hub.

Comment: @waldauf Thank you very much. There isn't any problem about registry server. I tried both our self host and docker hub. I can login and can pull. That's all okay. It seems the problem is the usage of Kubernetes.

Comment: @online Yesterday I solved the same problem with _Error syncing pod_. I checked where is pod running and there I checked kubelet service: `journalctl -fu kubelet.service`. And there I found out what was problem (in my case bad dir structure). Try it. ;]

Comment: @waldauf Thank you. I also known my reason. The application was something wrong. Not the bad of docker or k8s.

Comment: @online Great news. :]